# ec2 hangs on npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I have free tier ec2 (1GB RAB, 500MB swap memory)

When Jenkins performs `npm install` on the project, ec2 just hangs, stops responding and only reboot brings it to life.

With `htop`, I analysed the situation and figured out that RAM just exhausts and chokes and additional swap memory I created doesn't help.

Since I'm having a school project, I want to use free tier and somehow launch the project there (I tried `npm run build` too, but for now it has too many issues).

I tried yarn too, but there's an issue with different versions of `babel-loader` being required by two other packages.

Is there a way to perform `npm install` in an automatic fashion (so that Jenkins can do it with just a script shell) and without hanging ec2?

Comment: Can't you just run `$ npm install` locally and upload the `node_modules` folder up on the EC2 instance? That should negate needing to run `$ npm install` up on EC2 but you might need to run `$ npm install` in a Linux virtual machine so any native add-ons are compiled for the correct OS.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem where the server just would stop installing. While it is definitely possible to upload the node_modules manually, I preferred to let npm do it for me. I solved it by deleting half of the dependencies before running `npm install`. After it finished i added them back and ran `npm install` a second time. Now everything is installed.
From now on `npm install` should work fine, since most dependencies are already installed. However adding or updating many dependencies at once might result in a hanging server again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I had to restart the instance several times but it stayed in the middle of executing the command `npm i`

And the problem is that the new instance initially only has 1gib of ram, therefore when you execute the npm command the instance consumes all that ram, for this reason it freezes and never finishes installing.

The solution is to create or allocate swap memory, in my case I have Ubuntu Server 22.04, perform the following commands in order:

1. We create a 4GB directory for swap memory

```
fallacate -l 4G /swapfile
```

2. We grant read and write permission so that the system can use the directory

```
chmod 600 /swapfile
```

3. We assign the directory to the swap system

```
mkswap /swapfile

swapon /swapfile

swapon --show

free -h
```